# How to take the first value in a GROUP BY statement as an aggregation? [SQL BigQuery]

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, aggregation

I have a dataset of user_id, day_event, and day_joined. I want to `GROUP BY` user_id and day_event, then take the first of each group as determined by the earliest day_joined. However, I can't do this using `FIRST_VALUE`, as it's not an aggregation function. This statement works if I use `ANY_VALUE`, but I specifically need the first value.

This is what I have now:

```
SELECT user_id,
day_event,
FIRST_VALUE(day_joined) OVER(PARTITION BY day_joined ORDER BY day_joined) AS day_joined
FROM event_data
GROUP BY user_id, day_event
ORDER BY user_id, day_event
```

However, this returns the following error:
`SELECT list expression references day_joined which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [15:13]`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this with min() aggregation operator.
See the following code as example:

```
SELECT user_id,
day_event,
MIN(day_joined) AS day_joined
FROM event_data
GROUP BY user_id, day_event
ORDER BY user_id, day_event
```